# Toggle Service/Task using Shell Commands in Rails Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, shell, service, system

I have a method in my controller that is triggered by a link in my Rails application. Everything works perfectly in Development mode, but for whatever reason, it doesn't work in Production mode. Whenever I call one of the commands, it will turn its gears like it's trying to do something, but never actually does anything. However, the strange thing is that the REINDEX of the sunspot does work. I'm looking at my production logs and monitoring the PID files created by each of the services. Also, if I run these commands normally within my SSH Terminal session, they work fine.

```
  def toggle_service
    command = params[:string].to_s
    if command == 'stop_mailman_server'
      system("ruby #{::Rails.root}/script/mailman_daemon.rb stop")
    elsif  command == 'start_mailman_server'
      system("ruby #{::Rails.root}/script/mailman_daemon.rb start")
    elsif  command == 'start_search_server'
      system("rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env}")
    elsif  command == 'stop_search_server'
      system("rake sunspot:solr:stop RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env}")
    elsif  command == 'reindex_search_server'
      system("rake sunspot:reindex RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env}")
    end    
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Comment: Just for code improvement: use case instead of if / elsif and symbols :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. In both cases of the mailman and the sunspot solr, my production environment needed write access to the pid folder that it was creating the files on. When I ran the command to start/stop the services in the terminal, it worked find, but had to elevate the privileges of that folder to the rails/apache user.